# In rails build the relationship in the has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many

In the rails app, I have an advisor model and department model. An advisor has and belongs to many departments and a department has and belongs to many advisors.

If an advisor and a department already exist. I want to create the relationship between them, which essentially put the advisor_id and department_id in the advisors_departments joint table. Something like

```
advisor.departments.build(:id => @department_id)
```

doesn't work since the department is already exist.

Alternatively,it can be through a joint model to implement the many to many relationship, which will work around with it.

But I already chose to use the has_and_belongs_to, is there an easy way to create the association between the two existed instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
department = Department.find(@department_id)
advisor.departments << department
```

And RoR should take care of the rest : )